# Existence of an irreducible polynomial $f\in F[t]$ and a positive integer $n$ such that for all $v\in V, f(T)^n(v)=0$.

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, minimal-polynomials

> Let $V$ be a finite-dimensional vector space over a field $F$, and let $T: V\to V$ be a linear transformation. Suppose that for every $v\in V$ there exists an irreducible polynomial $f_v\in F[t]$ and a positive integer $n_y$ such that $f_v(T)^{n_v}(v)=0$. Prove that there is an irreducible polynomial $f\in F[t]$ and a positive integer $n$ such that for all $v\in V, f(T)^n(v)=0$.

---

My attempt:

Choose a basis of $V$: $\{v_1,...,v_n\}$ and let $f_{v_k}(T)^{n_{v_k}}(v_k)=0, k=1,...,n$, then we have for every $v\in V$, $g(T):=\prod_{k=1}^n f_{v_k}(T)^{n_{v_k}}$ annihilates $v$. Hence the minimal polynomial $p(t)\in F[t]$ of $T$ divides $g(t)$. So actually we are asked to prove that $g(t)$ equals some of $f_{v_k}(t)^{n_{v_k}}$. But how to prove it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I simplify your notation by writing $f_i:=f_{v_i}$ etc.

Now ask what kills $v_1+v_2$. Clearly $f_1^{n_1}(T)f_2^{n_2}(T)$ does, as does $h(T)^{m}$ for some irredcucible $h(t)$. If $h$ is coprime to both $f_1$ and $f_2$ then we see that $v_1+v_2$ is killed by $1=\mathrm{hcf}(h^m, f_1^{n_1}f_2^{n_2})$: a contradiction. So we may suppose without loss that $h=f_1$.

Let $N>m,n_1,n_2$. Then $f_1^N$ kills both $v_1$ and $v_1+v_2$, so that $f_1^N$ kills $v_2$. If $f_1$ and $f_2$ are coprime then $1$, the highest common factor of $f_1^N$ and $f_2^{n_2}$, kills $v_2$. This can't be so, hence $f_1=f_2$.

Now argue by induction on $n$.

Answer (score 0):

Let $x$ and $y$ linearly independent $f_x(T)^{n_x}(x)=f_y(T)^{n_y}=0$.

$f_x(T)^{n_x}f_y(T)^{n_y}(x+y)=0$, implies that $f_{x+y}$ divides $f_x(T)^{n_x}f_y(T)^{n_y}$ this implies that $f_{x+y}=f_x$ or $f_y$, if $f_{x+y}=f_x$, $f_x(T)^{n_{x+y}}(x+y)=f_x(T)^{n_{x+y}}(y)=0$ implies that $f_x=f_y$.

Answer (score 0):

The key point to show is that $f_v$, taken to be monic, cannot depend on $v$ (as long as $v\neq0$); then you can take the common value as $f$ (or, pedantically, take any irreducible polynomial if $\dim(V)=0$). Once this is shown, it will be obvious that some power of $f$ annihilates $T$, as the increasing chain of subspaces $\ker(f^k(T))$ for $k=0,1,2,\ldots$ has all of $V$ as its union.

So assume for a contradiction that $v,w$ be two nonzero vectors with $f_v\neq f_w$. With $p=f_v^{n_v}$ and $q=f_w^{n_w}$ there exist Bézout coefficients $r,s\in F[t]$ such that $pr+qs=1$. Then $(pr)[T](v+w)=v$ and $(qs)[T](v+w)=w$, so any polynomial $g$ with $g[T](v+w)=0$ also satisfies $g[T](v)=0$ and $g[T](w)=0$ (compose with $(pr)[T]$ respectively with $(qs)[T]$), hence such $g$ must be a common multiple of $f_v$ and $f_w$. But is was given that there exists an *irreducible* such $g$, and we have our contradiction.